# VS2005 nafxcw.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argv

Tags: mfc, release-mode

I get this error when i build a project which have static library input (.lib). The problem is that I can run the project successfully in debug but can't run in release mode.It shows the error as ....

```
nafxcw.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argv
nafxcw.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argc
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You can't run it or you can't build it?

Comment: Something probably related to your project settings in Debug vs. Release. Open Project --> Settings menu and compare both settings. Pay special attention to the settings under Linker.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's KB Q166504](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166504) might have the answer for you:

> When building an MFC application or DLL, you need to insure that all
>   relevant libraries are in sync:
>
> - If you have selected to build an application using MFC in the Shared Library, then you must also use the dynamic version of the C
>     Run-Time (MSVCRT.DLL).
> - If you have selected to build a debug MFC application, then you must also use the debug version of the C Run-Time. Similarly, release
>     MFC applications must use the non-debug version of the C Run-Time.
> - If your debug MFC application uses extension DLLs, every extension DLL must be a debug build as well. Again, release apps must match
>     release extension DLLs. The type of C Run-Time library is fixed.
>     Extension DLLs and the applications which use them must all use MFC in
>     the shared library, which requires the dynamic DLL version of the C
>     Run-Time.
> - If you are linking to any static libraries that also link to MFC or the CRT, you should ensure that every static library shares the
>     same properties (debug/release, CRT-static/dynamic) as the
>     application.
>
> RESOLUTION
>
> To change the type of C Run-Time library used by an application or
>   DLL, go to the Build/Project settings property sheet and switch to the
>   C/C++ tab. On the C/C++ page, choose the "Code Generation" category.
>   Change the value of the "Use run-time library" listbox. Pay careful
>   attention to make this specific for each configuration; only one
>   configuration, such as "Win32 (80x86) Debug," should be selected when
>   you change this value.
>
> - Debug, shared library MFC applications - "Debug Multithreaded Dll."
> - Release, shared library MFC applications - "Multithread Dll."
> - Debug, static library MFC applications - "Debug Multithreaded."
> - Release, static library MFC applications - "Multithreaded."